# How to not commit temporary debug statements

Tags: git, version-control

When debugging code, I'll often wrap variables of interest in a function call that simple print that variable's value and returns itself (I'm actually doing this in Haskell if it matters). These debugging statements are intended to be temporary, they're particularly designed to deal with the bug I'm attempting to resolve. So once it is resolved I don't want the clogging up the code.

What I find is I'll add these debug statements to a number of files, make some real changes, maybe add a few more debug statements, then some more changes, and then I may be happy it's good to go.

Some files will just have debug statements added, some files will have just real code changes, and others a mix.

But I don't want to commit all this debug code, as it'll likely be never used again.

So I need to search through the files and remove all the debug statements. If I miss some I'll get changes recorded that shouldn't be there.

Is there a way to strip out the debug statements from commits? I was thinking this may be a common issue and there may already be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a new branch (such as `hotfix`) to debug your code, and commit changes on it.

Then you can cherry pick the latest commit from `hotfix` to your current working branch (such as `master`), and solve the conflict manually. Details as below

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick hotfix
# solve the conflict files manually and keep the form you want
git add .
git cherry-pick --continue
```